# how do I create a signature on yosemite? preview does not offer that option

Tags: signature

how do I create a signature on yosemite?  preview does not offer that option as shown in the youtube of how to create a signature.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Tools menu > Annotate > Signature > Manage Signatures and use the "Create Signature" button at the bottom.